# Обновить поле в таблице п оусловию

Tags: oracle

Есть таблица tmp1 с полями code1  и status и таблица Tmp2 с полем code2

Как обновить поле status первой таблицы вставив в это поле значение "0" для всех записей из tmp1 код которых есть в  tmp2?

Comment: Ну например `UPDATE tmp1
SET status=0
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM tmp2
               WHERE tmp1.code1 = tmp2.code2 )`

Comment: А что делает этот подзапрос SELECT 1 FROM tmp2 WHERE tmp1.code1 = tmp2.code2 ??

Comment: Просто переведите его текст на русский язык.

Comment: если условие выполнено вернет 1?

Comment: Да. Но в данном случае важно, что подзапрос вообще что-то вернёт. Ведь перевести надо было весь запрос - и особенно два слова перед подзапросом.

Comment: Спасибо большое